# how to structure javascript array of object?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have below kind of kind of array of object data which contain nested array of object inside it, and I want to structure it based on what my Api needed.

```
 [{
            containerId: 'c12',
            containerNumber: '4321dkjkfdj',
            goods: [{
                weight: '32kg',
                quantity: '3'
            }]
        },
     { containerId: 'c12', containerNumber: '4321dkjkfdj', goods: [{
            weight: '322kg',
            quantity: '32'
        }]
    },
    
    {
        containerId: 'c13',
        containerNumber: '1212dkjkfdj',
        goods: [{
            weight: '13kg',
            quantity: '3'
        }]
    },
     {containerId: 'c13', containerNumber: '1212dkjkfdj', goods: [{
    weight: '13kg',
    quantity: '3'
    }]
    },

]
```

and I want to have an Object with same 'containerId' as a one object by including the 'goods' property that has the same 'containerId' like the below code:

```
    [{
        containerId: 'c12',
        containerNumber: '4321dkjkfdj',
        goods: [{
                weight: '32kg',
                quantity: '3'
            },
            {
                weight: '322kg',
                quantity: '32'
            }
        ]

    },
    {
        containerId: 'c13',
        containerNumber: '1212dkjkfdj',
        goods: [{
                weight: '13kg',
                quantity: '3'
            },
            {
                weight: '13kg',
                quantity: '3'
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: you can try a group by containerId

Answer (score 3):

You can iterate through the items and build a lookup object by using [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), where the key is `containerId` and values are `{containerId, containerNumber, goods}`. If a key is found in accumulator `a[containerId]` we just need to update `goods`.

```js
const arr = [{ containerId: 'c12', containerNumber: '4321dkjkfdj', goods: [{ weight: '32kg', quantity: '3' }] }, { containerId: 'c12', containerNumber: '4321dkjkfdj', goods: [{ weight: '322kg', quantity: '32' }] }, { containerId: 'c13', containerNumber: '1212dkjkfdj', goods: [{ weight: '13kg', quantity: '3' }] }, { containerId: 'c13', containerNumber: '1212dkjkfdj', goods: [{ weight: '13kg', quantity: '3' }] } ]

const res = arr.reduce((a,{containerId, containerNumber, goods}) => ((a[containerId] ??= {containerId, containerNumber, goods: []}).goods = [...a[containerId].goods, ...goods],a), {});
console.log(Object.values(res));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const a = [
    {
        containerId: 'c12',
        containerNumber: '4321dkjkfdj',
        goods: [{
            weight: '32kg',
            quantity: '3'
        }]
    },
    {
        containerId: 'c12',
        containerNumber: '4321dkjkfdj',
        goods: [{
            weight: '322kg',
            quantity: '32'
        }]
    },
    {
        containerId: 'c13',
        containerNumber: '1212dkjkfdj',
        goods: [{
            weight: '13kg',
            quantity: '3'
        }]
    },
    {
        containerId: 'c13',
        containerNumber: '1212dkjkfdj',
        goods: [{
            weight: '13kg',
            quantity: '3'
        }]
    }
]

const result = a.reduce((p, c) => {
    const found = p.findIndex(p => p.containerId === c.containerId);
    found === -1 ? p.push(c) : p[found].goods.push(c.goods);
    return p
}, []);

console.log(result);
```